# C# - Redirect child process input to read what win service parent process writes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading a lot about the topic but I am not able to get it. I have an SSCCE with a service who create a child process with CreateProcessAsUser. This child process is only intended to read from its stdin; what parent process writes, but I don't get anything from parent.

Parent service code:

```
    public static unsafe int WriteToHandle(byte[] buffer, int index, int count, IntPtr hStdOut)
    {
        int n = 0;
        bool cont = true;

            fixed (byte* p = buffer)
            {
               cont = WriteFile(hStdOut, p + index, count, &n, 0);

            }
        return n;
    }

    public static bool StartProcessAsCurrentUser()
    {
        var hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        var sInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        var procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
        int iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser;
        string cmdLine = "ClientFormApp.exe";

        sInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];

        bool result = false;

        const int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
        const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
        const int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 0x102;
        const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0x0;
        const int HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT = 1;

        try
        {
            var tSecurity = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            tSecurity.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSecurity);
            var pSecurity = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            pSecurity.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSecurity);
            pSecurity.bInheritHandle = true; 

            IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(pSecurity));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(pSecurity, pointer, true);

            if (!CreatePipe(out hReadOut, out hWriteOut, pointer, 0)) // hReadOut -> read data from output | hWriteOut -> send data to output
                return result = false;
            if (!CreatePipe(out hReadIn, out hWriteIn, pointer, 0)) // hReadOut -> read data from output | hWriteOut -> send data to output
                return result = false;

            if (!SetHandleInformation(hWriteOut, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT))
                return result = false;
            if (!SetHandleInformation(hReadOut, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT))
                return result = false;

            if (!SetHandleInformation(hWriteIn, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT))
                return result = false;
            if (!SetHandleInformation(hReadIn, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT))
                return result = false;

            sInfo.hStdOutput = hWriteOut; 
            sInfo.hStdInput = hReadIn; 
            sInfo.hStdError = hWriteOut; 

            if (!GetSessionUserToken(ref hUserToken))
            {
                throw new Exception("StartProcessAsCurrentUser: GetSessionUserToken failed.");
            }

            uint dwCreationFlags = CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | (uint)CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
            sInfo.wShowWindow = (short)SW.SW_SHOW;
            sInfo.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

            if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hUserToken, false))
            {
                throw new Exception("StartProcessAsCurrentUser: CreateEnvironmentBlock failed.");
            }

            if (!CreateProcessAsUser(hUserToken,
                null, // Application Name
                cmdLine, // Command Line
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                true,
                dwCreationFlags,
                pEnv,
                null, // Working directory
                ref sInfo,
                out procInfo))
            {
                throw new Exception("StartProcessAsCurrentUser: CreateProcessAsUser failed.\n");
            }

            iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string message = "Message";
            byte[] messageByte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            int bytesWrited = WriteToHandle(messageByte, 0, messageByte.Length, hWriteIn);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Clossing handles
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have verified that bytesWrited is not 0.

Following [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this is my child process:

```
    public static unsafe int ReadFromHandle(byte[] buffer, int index, int count, IntPtr hStdOut)
    {
        int n = 0;

        try
        {
            fixed (byte* p = buffer)
            {
                if (!ReadFile(hStdOut, p + index, count, &n, 0)) //Nothing to read from handle
                    return 0;
            }
            return n;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnNewStep()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
        const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;
        string content = "";

        hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

        do
        {
            bytesReadOutput = ReadFromHandle(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, hStdin);
            content = content + System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReadOutput);
        }
    }
```

But `bytesReadOutput` is always 0. I don't really understand the purpose of the line `hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`. If I'm not wrong, when I create the child process in service process, I'm setting redirected standard input here `sInfo.hStdInput = hReadIn;` and `hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` in child process will get that `hReadIn` service handle. But I have checked it and `hStdin` is always 0.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're P/Invoke-ing all of this, rather than just using the functionality in System.Diagnostics.Process/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo which does support stream redirection and running as a different user?  hStdin being NULL/0 will definitely be an issue - have you tried calling GetLastError()?  The documentation does say that GetStdHandle will return null "If an application does not have associated standard handles, such as a service running on an interactive desktop, and has not redirected them".

Comment: @Ben I'm trying it in that way because I need to show a Form to the current user, and, from what I've seen, I cannot launch process as another user using ProcessStartInfo, unless I specify his name and password, which I don't know.  The form is displayed to the current user, but I'm not able to print anything in the box.

Yes, I have tried GetLastError. It reponses with an 183 (Cannot create a file when that file already exists), but I don't know the reason.

Comment: What about using Console.OpenStandardInput within your child process?

Comment: BTW. Desperately, I have tried to cast hReadIn to int, and pass it as an argument in CreateProcess, and then, reconvert it again as IntPtr in child side, and it works... But it seems a little bit tatty.

Comment: Agreed - I think handle values are not guaranteed to be unique cross-process though in practice it seems they are and this is unlikely to change.

Comment: @Ben, using Console.OpenStandardInput I don't read anything :(